# TDD type methodology for WPF / Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, tdd

Has anyone got a TDD-ish methodology for designing complex WPF xaml components (i.e., ControlTemplates, Custom Controls with dependency properties)?

Is eyeballing the UI the closest you can come to asserting your code is correct? How about incremental development; any aids to dividing up the logic incrementally?

If there isn't any methodologies for doing this now, do you think there will be as the platform continues to mature and gain adoption?

Cheers,
Berryl

To be more focused and avoid introductions to TDD, please consider the topic for an audience that is fairly seasoned in applying TDD to a traditional code base (including MVVM).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The silverlight toolkit provides all the unit test and the source code...
on
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

For UI testing I think some folks use the Silverlight Accessibility api
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707824(VS.95).aspx
....

And there are also tools for UI testing, too

MSDN Magazine article on UI-Testing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483216.aspx

Testing using WPF UI automation
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/testing-using-wpf-ui-automation)

It is surely not an easy and obvious topic and it always depends on the business case...

And for TDD in general look at this book: The art of Unit Testing...