# Test Driven Development - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, tdd

I'd like to shift my code to a more test driven development model, but am unsure the best way to do this for the presentation layer.

Other layers behave like a black box where you can give input and expect output.

The presentation layer is not so simple. Are there any programs, guides, or practices to help with test driven xaml development.

Comment: Your question has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479148/tdd-type-methodology-for-wpf-silverlight

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @mydogisbox. Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can mark this question as answered and give you credit for doing so?

Comment: I tried... it won't let me because the answer only consists of a link back to stackoverflow.

Comment: Odd. Try mentioning the comment you added verbally without the link. It should be clear to people reading the answer what's going on and should allow me to give you the proper karma for finding an answer.

Comment: For display apps, look for MVP or MVVM patterns. They significantly aid the testability of GUI Apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something from microsoft on the topic.  For further information, see the link in the comments.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483216.aspx

Comment: Thanks and sorry it took so much effort to give you the credit you deserve.

Comment: No problem.  I would suggest searching SO before posting next time.

Comment: This article doesn't mention anything about MVVM whose primary motivation is to increase testability of the application by seperating presentation from logic. The answer below is a much better answer.

Comment: @JasonTuran for the record, I use MVVM.  He explicitly asked for ways to test a UI, so that's what I answered.

Answer (score 13):

Well I cannot refrain from posting an answer. The approach shown in the accepted answer is a maintenance-trap to say the least.

Move your GUI development to the MVP / MVVM model. WPF is MVVM friendly.
Make thin GUIs (with minimal code/logic) that delegate/sync with a Presenter class. This means that you can write unit tests against the presenter and test a significant portion of your code without the UI. Write only a handful of UI tests and perform the majority of your functional testing using the presenter class.

Writing UI tests isn't the answer (for non-trivial GUIs) because they are

- unreadable. UI tests degenerate into long arcane scripts that are manipulating UI elements. It is difficult to see *what* is being tested since the *how* obscures it. If you can't read it, it'll take you longer to fix it once it breaks.
- slow. You'd be running fewer tests per unit of time.
- brittle. A Gui change can break a number of your GUI-coupled tests even though the functionality isn't. More test maintenance.
- unstable. You'd have to invest some amount of time in stabilizing the tests so that they run reliably each time. Introducing delays or polling for some things to show up.

Comment: For the record your recommendation is currently being put into practice.

Comment: @JSWork - Glad to hear that.. do postback of how it turned out ; hurdles/issues faced if any.

Comment: @Gishu Would you talk more about delegating to a presenter class? I have a WPF/MVVM app which I've neglected to create unit tests for because of the thickness of the GUI.

Comment: @MarkRichman - that would take up a few pages :) http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html Here's a good one.

Comment: @Gishu It seems to me that WPF/MVVM itself does this work. I guess I'm missing the secret sauce of how to make my GUIs more unit-test-friendly.

Comment: @MarkRichman - if you can elaborate on 'test-friendly', i can take a crack at answering that. Once you use MVVM, then there are 2 things you can do to a GUI, doX (commands) and getX (properties). Both are easy to test via 'silent/GUI-less' tests

Comment: @Gishu well I am already using MVVM, with databinding to ViewModels, so I have the properties and commands already in place. There are a number of things I simply don't know how to test, such as "Does this modal options dialog properly save edited values?" and things of that nature. I also have a number of very long-running async operations that I don't know how to test (i.e. installation progress).